# Is there a standard pattern for writing a linux command-line utility in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, command-line

This template should include command-line argument handling, version, and help.  Otherwise, can you suggest a link to a developer's guide?

Comment: getopt manual, perhaps?

Comment: "Is there a standard pattern for writing a linux command-line utility in C++?" - yeah, write it in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX guidelines for utilities are [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) and conventions succinctly described [here](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/essential/attributes/_posix.html).  [GNU extensions](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html) are common and I think pretty much expected on Linux.

Jonathan Leffler wrote a nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2160165/63743) here which delves into some of this as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a library which manages command line argumments. I recommend you the [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/program_options.html) library.

Comment: The Boost options lib is a convenient tool but I don't think it (or the associated docs) has much to say about designing the options for linux conventions.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of other answers, I would suggest considering GNU libc [argp](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html) functions.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any sort of standard pattern per se.  Once glance at the source for many of your favorite command line apps will reveal it's even more ad-hoc than you think.

Command line parsing is typically done with the [getopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) function.  As for help and version.  Either printf or cout.

You could also take a read of [The Art Of Unix Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131429019) about expected behaviors of command line programs in UNIX.

Comment: GNU libc also gives the `getopt_long` function which might be more useful....