# Can use the command "git commit -ma" to commit several staged files to my local repository and write a log message at the same time?

Tags: git, command-line

I'm teaching myself web development and am trying to get more comfortable with using Git to track changes to my personal projects.

I'm re-familiarizing myself with Git by by refactoring some code from an online Flask tutorial on YouTube and I was wondering if two discrete subcommands like: "git commit -a" and "git commit -m" can be combined into one command to save me time and effort.

### This is more of a general knowledge question since there isn't a wrong answer or error message/bug I'm stuck on.

There are some answers to old questions on here about skipping over steps in Git's workflow (e.g., using "git commit -am" to commit modified files before they've been staged) so a helpful answer would be more general and not overly prescriptive about the Do & Don'ts of any particular stage.

I'm just trying to learn more about how Git works as a beginner without creating a giant mess of version history that forces me to undo a bunch of mistakes while I'm still learning the basics. There'll be plenty of time for that later :p

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it works on your machine to use `git commit -ma`, but messing up the order of options is **not a good habit**. Commands using options in commonly used order is easier to understand, and less probable to cause error.

Sometimes messing up the order of the options don't matter, but options with its "parameter", such as `-m`, `-f` in `git commit [-m "message"]`, `tar [-x][-c][-v][-f filename]` **should not** be in wrong order.

For example, when using `tar`, the `-f` option can specify an archive. When using `tar -xvf [filename]`, it works. But when using `tar -fxv [filename]` or some other orders, the mistake will cause error.

Answer (score 2):

There are [many traditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option) on command-line interface and many different parsers. Git coming from Linux kernel authors follow [Unix standard conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) with GNU long options extension. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2160165/7976758) and follow links in it for gory details about POSIX standards and traditions.

There are flags (also named switches, options that change behavior in binary way: yes/no, true/false, left/right, up/down) and options with parameters. There're short, single-letter options; and there're long options. Short options denoted with a single dash; example : `-a`. Long options use double dash: `--all`.

Short options can be combined: `-a -b` can be written as `-ab`. Options with arguments could be combined with flags but only in the correct order. You can combine `git commit -a -m "message"` into `git commit -am "message"` but not into `git commit -ma "message"` because Git parses `-ma` as "value 'a' for option `-m`" and `"message"` left unprocessed and passed to `git commit` which complain about unknown file name:

```
$ git commit -ma "message"
error: pathspec 'message' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Long options cannot be combined.

Options with parameters can be written in sticky way (argument is glued to its option like this: `-m"message"`, `--message="message"`) and non-sticky (argument separated from the option with spaces: `-m "message"`, `--message "message"`). This is about generic Unix parsers, and different programs have different recommendations and traditions about stickiness.

Git authors provide [many recommendations](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcli) on how to use Git CLI.

Some options cannot be combined. For example you can do `git log -p -5` ("show me 5 commits with patches") but you cannot shorten them to `git log -p5` nor to `-5p`:

```
$ git log -p5
fatal: unrecognized argument: -p5

$ git log -5p
fatal: '5p': not a non-negative integer
```

This is because `-5` is actually a shortcut for `-n5`. You cannot combine it with `-pn5` but can do `-n5p`.

The most complex case is an option that allows an optional argument but doesn't require it because it has a default. `git grep` has option [`-O`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--Oltpagergt) that passes found files via a program; default is pager `less`. But it's possible to name a different program; I often use `vim`:

```
$ git grep -Ovim pattern
```

In that case program name **must be** written sticky. Non-sticky argument (`git grep -O vim`) makes option `-O` to use its default (`less`) and `vim` will be passed to `git grep` with which `grep` will fail.

Git uses subcommands, and you must understand that command [`git` has its own set of options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git), different from subcommands options. You can write `git --no-pager log` but cannot `git log --no-pager` — long option `--no-pager` is an option for `git` but not for `git log`:

```
$ git log --no-pager
fatal: unrecognized argument: --no-pager
```

At the very end my personal advice: use short options (combined or not) in the command line. But use long options when writing scripts, documentation and Stack Overflow questions and answers; long options are mostly self-documenting. At least use long options more often.

Answer (score 1):

`git commit -am 'the message'` is the way to go.

If you want the interactive editor, just use `git commit -a` and the editor (defined by your environment variable `$EDITOR`) will launch.