# Is there any opensource cross platform C++ library for creating menus for command line projects?

Tags: c++, frameworks, cross-platform, console-application

So what I need on developer side is something like

```
addoption("-use-something", "Use Something instead of Some other thing", localVarName, desiredValue, defauultValue);
```

While on user side I wish to see 3 things

- first is to set params in if they were passed as application options/arguments (like from `start my.exe -use-something` )
- second is to read user intput for "help" key word and trace all possible commands with descriptions
- last is to read on app start up commands if some developers cin.get() is not already doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/program_options.html). Example from the [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html):

```
// Declare the supported options.
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("compression", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);    

if (vm.count("help")) {
    cout << desc << "\n";
    return 1;
}

if (vm.count("compression")) {
    cout << "Compression level was set to " 
 << vm["compression"].as<int>() << ".\n";
} else {
    cout << "Compression level was not set.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the answers of [Option Parsers for C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637371/option-parsers-for-c-c)